# Blender 2.75a has massive lag

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu, blender

I'm running Blender 2.75a Game Engine on Ubuntu 14.04.

My system specs are:

- 4GB RAM
- Intel Core 2 Duo
- Nvidia Geforce 210

Once I select the `Texture` mode the program begins to lag hugely, taking several seconds > 10 simply to bring up a selection dialog.

Having used 2.69 previously and encountering no lag problems whatsoever, I'm thinking that this new version is too power-intense on my GPU, is this correct? If so, what should be the minimum GPU I should be using.

**Edit**: I've tried using Blender 2.74 and the lag is still there, albeit a little less.

Comment: As different blender versions have variations on the same hardware/software I would [report it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/) The biggest problem is the number of versions between working and not, can you try other versions between 2.69 and 2.75 to narrow down when the change happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really using an [Nvidia GeForce 210](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/specifications) the hangup could very well just be the old hardware. Circuits age, boards start to mess up and eventually die. You're issue likely has almost nothing to do with Ubuntu and everything to do with your hardware.

I would say step up to something in the GTX series, even if it's one of the older GTX cards it should still be way faster than what you say you're using. I would avoid AMD cards as they seem to still have some issues with Linux as far as drivers are concerned.

Comment: Go for a ATI Radeon R5 series for some good performance.

Comment: Or an R7 or R9 if you really want the best.  R9 390X is the best right now.